# Form input field value issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to input email value from user and store it in a state variable. I have tried the following code but getting an error:

```
<Form.Control type="email" required placeholder="Enter email" value={this.state.email}  onChange={this.setEmail}></Form.Control>
```

State variable is defined as follow:

```
this.state = {
    email: '',
}
```

Following is my code to set the value entered by user in email:

```
setEmail = (e) => {
    this.setState(() => ({email: e.target.value}))
}
```

I tried printing e.target.value. It is correct. But while running this code, I am getting error:

```
Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

Any comments on how to fix this issue?

Comment: can you add more details

Comment: It looks like some kind of a library for form handling. I guess just a value is being passed, not whole event. `=> ({ email: e })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because the event is not persisted, and it is used in an asynchronous function (*`setState` is async*).

Just extract it before calling `setState`.

```
setEmail = (e) => {
    const {value} = e.target;
    this.setState(() => ({email: value}))
}
```